# How to georeference a map using Python

Tags: python, gdal, georeferencing

Can somebody help me please to georeference a map with Python?
Maybe I'm not setting right the row and column numbers?
This is my code:

```
import shutil
from osgeo import gdal, osr

orig_fn = 'G:/Egyetem/UBB Geomatica/Disertatie/EMSR365_AOI01_GRA_PRODUCT_r1_RTP01_v1.jpg'
output_fn = 'G:/Egyetem/UBB Geomatica/Disertatie/output2.tif'

# Create a copy of the original file and save it as the output filename:
shutil.copy(orig_fn, output_fn)

# Open the output file for writing for writing:
ds = gdal.Open(output_fn, gdal.GA_Update)

# Set spatial reference:
sr = osr.SpatialReference()
sr.ImportFromEPSG(32631) #My projection system

# Enter the GCPs
#   Format: [map x-coordinate(longitude)], [map y-coordinate (latitude)], [elevation],
#   [image column index(x)], [image row index (y)]

gcps = [gdal.GCP(280000, 4590000, 0, 417, 499),
        gdal.GCP(310000, 4590000, 0, 4354, 499),
        gdal.GCP(310000, 4560000, 0, 4354, 4437)]

# Apply the GCPs to the open output file:
ds.SetGCPs(gcps, sr.ExportToWkt())

# Close the output file in order to be able to work with it in other programs:
ds = None
```

This error occurs:
[image]
Here is my original map:
https://we.tl/t-dn6uIilxJq

Comment: It looks like `gdal` does not recognize `output_fn` because `ds` is `None`. Make sure the file exists.

Comment: Yes, it exists. It was created.

Comment: Ok, I just noticed you need to convert the JPG file to TIFF first. You can use `gdal.Translate()` for that. Using `shutil.copy()` and changing the extension is not enough.

Comment: Can you help me please what arguments I should put in `gdal.Translate()`

Comment: Okey. I resolved: `out_ds = gdal.Translate('G:/Egyetem/UBB Geomatica/Disertatie/EMSR365_AOI01_GRA_PRODUCT_r1_RTP01_v1.tif', orig_fn)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gdal` does not recognize your TIFF file. It is most likely due to the fact that you copied the original JPG file and just changed the extension to `.tif`. In order to properly convert your JPG file to a TIFF file you should use the `gdal.Translate()` function. The most basic call to the function could look like:

```py
ds = gdal.Translate('test.tif', orig_fn)
```

However, there are several arguments you can specifiy. You can take a look at the [documentation](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#TranslateOptions).

Then, you can use the rest of your code:

```
# Set spatial reference:
sr = osr.SpatialReference()
sr.ImportFromEPSG(32631) #My projection system

# Enter the GCPs
#   Format: [map x-coordinate(longitude)], [map y-coordinate (latitude)], [elevation],
#   [image column index(x)], [image row index (y)]

gcps = [gdal.GCP(280000, 4590000, 0, 417, 499),
        gdal.GCP(310000, 4590000, 0, 4354, 499),
        gdal.GCP(310000, 4560000, 0, 4354, 4437)]

# Apply the GCPs to the open output file:
ds.SetGCPs(gcps, sr.ExportToWkt())

# Close the output file in order to be able to work with it in other programs:
ds = None
```